# PHP mailer with recaptcha does not send reply email

Tags: php, captcha

I have two functions in my controller.php
Both are called at form submit, handled by php mailer lite.

I added the first function "verzenden" what sends the email to the company, in a Google recaptcha script to validate.

When i test the form, the email will send to the Company address.
But the reply email to the requester wil not send.
I received this error "You must provide at least one recipient email address."

I have checked the controller file but can't find why the reply does not send.
I guess it has something to do with passing the variable to the "sendReply" function.

Thanks in advance.

```
function verzenden() { 

    // Checks if form has been submitted
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        function post_captcha($user_response) {
            $fields_string = '';
            $fields = array(
                'secret' => 'XXXXXXXX',
                'response' => $user_response
            );
            foreach($fields as $key=>$value)
            $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
            $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string, '&');

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);

            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);

            return json_decode($result, true);
        }

        // Call the function post_captcha
        $res = post_captcha($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);

        if (!$res['success']) {
            // What happens when the CAPTCHA wasn't checked
            echo '<div class="recaptcha-alert-box"><p>Please go back and make sure you check the security CAPTCHA box.</p></div>';
        } else {
            // If CAPTCHA is successfully completed...



            if(!empty($this->data)) { 

                include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/vendors/phpmailer_lite.php");

                $fromname = "Company";
                $fromaddress = "info@company.com";

                $email_to = $this->getSetting("EMAIL_TO");

                $to = $email_to['Setting']['value'];

                $mail = new PHPMailerLite(); 

                $mail->IsMail(); 

                $style = "<style>";
                    $style .= " body, td { font-family: verdana; font-size: 13px; } ";
                    $style .= " table { width: 500px; border: 1px solid #CCC; } ";
                    $style .= " td { width: 50%; } ";
                $style .= "</style>";

                $body = "<table>";          
                    $body .= "<tr>";
                        $body .= "<td>Bedrijfsnaam</td>";
                        $body .= "<td>".$this->data['Contact']['Firma']."</td>";
                    $body .= "</tr>";   

                    $body .= "<tr>";
                        $body .= "<td>Naam</td>";
                        $body .= "<td>".$this->data['Contact']['Naam']."</td>";
                    $body .= "</tr>";   

                    $body .= "<tr>";
                        $body .= "<td>Adres</td>";
                        $body .= "<td>".$this->data['Contact']['Adres']."</td>";
                    $body .= "</tr>";   

                    $body .= "<tr>";
                        $body .= "<td>Postcode</td>";
                        $body .= "<td>".$this->data['Contact']['Postcode']."</td>";
                    $body .= "</tr>";

                    $body .= "<tr>";
                        $body .= "<td>Woonplaats</td>";
                        $body .= "<td>".$this->data['Contact']['Woonplaats']."</td>";
                    $body .= "</tr>";   

                    $body .= "<tr>";
                        $body .= "<td>Telefoonnummer</td>";
                        $body .= "<td>".$this->data['Contact']['Telefoon']."</td>";
                    $body .= "</tr>";   

                    $body .= "<tr>";
                        $body .= "<td>Emailadres</td>";
                        $body .= "<td>".$this->data['Contact']['Email']."</td>";
                    $body .= "</tr>";   

                    $body .= "<tr>";
                        $body .= "<td>Interesse</td>";
                        $body .= "<td>".$this->data['Contact']['Interesse']."</td>";
                    $body .= "</tr>";   

                    $body .= "<tr>";
                        $body .= "<td>Omschrijving</td>";
                        $body .= "<td>".$this->data['Contact']['Omschrijving']."</td>";
                    $body .= "</tr>";

                $body .= "</table>";

                $mail->SetFrom($fromaddress, $fromname);

                $mail->AddAddress($to);


                $mail->Subject = "[Verzonden naar: ".$to."][Ticket Nr. #".$this->getNewLabelID()."] Contactformulier";

                $mail->AltBody = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

                $mail->MsgHTML($style.$body);

                if(!$mail->Send()) {

                    @mail("info@developer.nl", "DEVELOPER Mailer error  - LITE", $mail->ErrorInfo."\n\nEmail adres: ".$to."\n\nSubject: ".$subject."\n\nBody: ".$body."");                  

                }

                $this->sendReply($this->data['Contact']['Email']);


            }

            $sent = $this->getSetting("EMAIL_THANKS");

            $this->redirect("/".$sent['Setting']['value']); 


        }
    } 

    }





        function sendReply($email) { 

            include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/vendors/phpmailer_lite.php");

            $fromname = "Company";
            $fromaddress = "info@company.com";

            $to = $email;

            $mail = new PHPMailerLite(); 

            $mail->IsMail(); 

            $style = "<style>";
                $style .= " body, td { font-family: verdana; font-size: 13px; } ";
                $style .= " table { width: 500px; border: 1px solid #CCC; } ";
                $style .= " td { width: 50%; } ";
            $style .= "</style>";

            $reply = $this->getSetting('EMAIL_REPLY', $_SESSION['taal']);

            $body = $reply['Setting']['value'];

            $mail->SetFrom($fromaddress, $fromname);

            $mail->AddAddress($to);


            $mail->Subject = "Automatische reply: contactformulier";

            $mail->AltBody = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

            $mail->MsgHTML($style.$body);

            if(!$mail->Send()) {

                @mail("info@developer.nl", "DEVELOPER Mailer error - LITE", $mail->ErrorInfo."\n\nEmail adres: ".$to."\n\nSubject: ".$subject."\n\nBody: ".$body."");                   

            }

        }
```

Comment: _“I guess it has something to do with passing the variable to the "sendReply" function.”_ - stop guessing, and _verify_ instead! Make a debug output inside of the function, to check if `$email` actually contains what you think it should. And please go enable proper PHP error reporting, if you have not done that yet.

Comment: Yeah I understand. Its a system im not familiar with....  Anyway I fixed the validation with javascript.

Comment: on a side note you should factorize your code, this is very heavy ot read. :)